# Different spacing between cells with UICollectionView and FlowLayout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell, spacing

I have a problem with dynamic cell sizing in a UICollectionView, or maybe a logic problem. I would like to calculate the width of the cells in `sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath`. I have a minimum spacing of `1`. The problem is that the board/spacing between my three cells is not the same as you can see in the picture. The spacing between the first and second cell looks bigger than the spacing between the second and the third cell.

[image]

My code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 9
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    cell.name.text = "My Textfield"
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = mycollectionView.frame.width
    let cellsInLine: CGFloat = 3
    let widthWithoutSpacing = width - (spacing * (cellsInLine - 1))
    let cell = CGSize(width: widthWithoutSpacing / cellsInLine, height: 50)
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return spacing
}
```

Comment: Did you test/see it on a device as well? This could be simply a simulator distortion.
Side note: there is no need to set the cell width explicitly, specified spacing and collection view constraints should be enough to let AutoLayout do its job.

Comment: Agreed with @Fayer. I used to run into the same situation, when the border is really thin, sometimes simulator doesn't render it correctly. Try to test on real device, it might be fine.

Comment: Its the same problem on the real device. I think the problem is that the width of the cell in this case is not even. When I say the with is rounded everything looks clear like: `let cell = CGSize(width: unroundedWith.rounded(.down), height: 50)
`

Comment: With rounded() I have a cell width of `137` per cell and a spacing of `1.5` between the cells. `137 * 3 + 2 * 1.5` is exactly the width of the device.